# Си. Что должна возвращать функция, которая определяет, входит в состав данного символьной строки указанное пользователем ключевое слово

Tags: c

Что должна возвращать эта функция? И как на основе определить в каком из предложений больше раз встречается ключевое слово?

Написала программу, но как сделать все в функции?

Написать функцию, которая определяет, входит в состав данного символьной строки указанное пользователем ключевое слово. На основе разработанной функции определить, в каком из предложений больше раз встречается заданное ключевой набор символов.

```
int main() 
{
   char cszSentences[5][100] = {0 };
   for (int i=0, i<5.i++)
   {
       gets(cszSentences[i])
   }
   char szKeyword[10];
   printf("Choose a keyword\n");
   gets(szKeyword); 
   int iLen = strlen(szKeyword);
   int n = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   { 
      for(const char *src = cszSentences[i]; (src = strstr(src, szKeyword)) != 0;
          src += iLen)
      {
         n++;
      } 
      printf("in %d sentence is %d keywords\n", i+1, n);
      n = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Если она определяет "входит или нет" - то возвращать она должна bool.

Comment: Думаю, она должна возвращать всё-таки int. Например, номер предложения, в котором большее число раз встречается искомое слово, если оно там вообще есть, и -1, если слова такого нет.

Comment: Указатель на начало найденного в строке слова или NULL, если не нашла (собственно, стандартная [strstr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) ведет себя именно так)

Comment: `На основе разработанной функции определить, в каком из предложений больше раз встречается заданное ключевой набор символов.` -- вместе с подсчетом `n` в том же цикле ищите *максимум* из них и запоминайте соответствующее `i`. После цикла задача решена.

Comment: Так "ключевой набор символов" или "ключевое слово"? Это - принципиальная разница.  "Набор символов" это подстрока. А "слово" это обычно не просто подстрока, а, скажем, подстрока обрамленная пробелами.